# Integrating a standalone Solr search server with grails domain object_

Tags: grails, solr

I need to integrate a standalone Apache Solr server to my grails application. I know there is a solr plugin for grails, but it embeds the solr server and the plugin don't seem to actively maintained.

My main question is how to index the fields in my domain objects. I want to update the index when I create/update/delete my domain objects. I guess it can be done via a afterInsert/afterUpdate/afterDelete event. But there must be some smarter (=less code in the domain objects) way of doing this?

Comment: how about embeding the solr sever into your grails app? then you can search and index data using solrj

Comment: Are there any downsides to embedding it inside the grails app?

Answer (score 1):

You can register an hibernate event listener, or use a event publishing/listeningn mechanism like this -> http://grailsrocks.github.io/grails-platform-core/guide/events.html

Then, when your domain objects are changed, just update them in the solr, using solr plugin